# ASP.NET MVC Action Gives 404 on Certain Params?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, http-status-code-404

I'm getting a strange error in my MVC site. I have an action in my controller which responds to the default route of {controller}/{action}/{id} - in my case, /Project/Client/{id}.

Depending on the id I pass to it, I get an error. With Elmah off, it's a straight-up ASP.NET 404 error. Turning Elmah on gives me the following:

```
System.Web.HttpException
   at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetConfigPathData(String configPath)
   at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetVirtualPathData(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean permitPathsOutsideApp)
   at System.Web.HttpContext.GetFilePathData()
   at System.Web.HttpContext.GetConfigurationPathData()
   at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetConfig(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpContext.get_ImpersonationToken()
   at System.Web.ClientImpersonationContext.Start(HttpContext context, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ThreadContext.SetImpersonationContext()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ThreadContext.Enter(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
```

This only happens with certain ID params. for example

```
/Projects/Client/ABC -- works
/Projects/Client/DEF -- works
/Projects/Client/GHI -- 404
/Projects/Client/JKL -- works
```

and so on...

Any clues?

Comment: Do you have any other routes set up in your application?

Comment: I have one that also adds a page param, so {controller}/{action}/{id}/{page}

Comment: Do you have a unit test for the "GHI" example?  It would help to be sure that you really have a routing problem and not a problem in the Controller logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Phil Haacks route debugger to learn which routes are being called
read here:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Comment: This didn't uncover any problems, but it introduced me to a nifty new tool that solved a problem in another project, so awarding the answer to you, in absence of any better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should look at is your web.config files in your site. The top of your stack trace;

```
at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetConfigPathData(String configPath)
```

Looks to be a call to determine the location of the web.config. It may be that the virtual file system being defined by your routes (`/Project/client/id`) is conflicting with a web.config that may exist at, say, `~/Project/web.config`

It's a bit of a wild stab derived from the stack trace, but shouldn't take too long to see if it might be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else shows up on this page and doesn't find the solution they are looking for, certain character strings are not allowed in URLs. Read about it here:

[Weird 404 error in ASP.NET MVC when including "con"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301736/weird-404-error-in-asp-net-mvc-when-including-con)

The solution is another of Microsoft's "WorkProperly" flags (whose default value is "false")