# Weird 404 error in ASP.NET MVC when including "con"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm going through some of the crawl errors on an MVC application I maintain, and found a 404 error for a URL that looked like it should be valid.

The URL is of the format: `/gifts/{categoryName}/{productName}/{productId}/`

For some reason, when the productName is set to the value "con" I just get a 404 error. Any other value (different or same length of string) and it seems to work fine.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this before?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`con` is a reserved word and therefore cannot be put in an MVC route

You need to add the following to your web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/>

    <!-- ... your other settings ... -->
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

See this article for more information:

[Putting the Con (COM1, LPT1, NUL, etc.) Back in your URLs](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx)

Comment: That's a great shout! Just made the change to my web.config and it's working fine now... I shall have a read up on that. Many thanks.